# tab completion crashes bash after sourcing a file

Tags: 16.04, bash

I am a heavy user of Tab completion, e.g. `git ch <TAB>` becomes `git checkout`. Normally this works.

I have a script that exports an environment variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail

export AN_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=true
```

I source it:

```
$ . ./bash_crash_test.bash
```

I type some things and hit Tab to auto-complete:

```
$ git ch <TAB>
```

and the shell / terminal / console exits. If I'm using Terminator or Tilix, the tile exits.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` + reboot does not fix the problem. I *can* run scripts all day long, no problem. I have been doing `export`s in scripts which then run other scripts, no problems there.

I haven't found any *reproducible* problems with bash exiting with autocomplete on the Interwebz.

bash version: `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Using vanilla Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It's not the variable export that's causing that - it's the inappropriate use of `set -e`. See for example [Enabling 'set -e' in the shell causes bash-completion to terminate the shell.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668265)